# Does the accuracy of prediction of a neural network vary for different sizes of training and test data everytime we run it

Tags: matlab, neural-network

I have a function `y=(x1)^2 + 2*(x2 )+(x3 )+ 3*(x4)^3` of which I have to predict the value. So I have 4 inputs in input layer, 1 hidden layer and 2 nodes in output layer. Default output is `[1 0]` if `y` is positive and output is `[0 1]` if `y` is negative.

Inputs are between `0` and `1`, weights between `-1` and `1`. Alpha is `0.01` and threshold is `0.005`.

When I train my data for 200 examples , I get 94% on training data and 86% on test data(for 4 nodes in hidden layer).

I get 90.2% accuracy on a training set of 250 examples and 96% on test data. And also running the same program again yields different accuracy on training and test data(due to randomised weights).

So now can u suggest how exactly can I increase my accuracy to achieve 98% - 100%.

Comment: Could you please provide some training data with inputs and targets?

Comment: [0.6294 0.8116 -0.7460 0.8267] , target [1 0]

Comment: And the range of input is actually -1 to 1, another input  [0.2647 -0.8049 -0.4430 0.0938], target [0 1]. [

Comment: Thanks for that! But i need some more infos: Do you use any matlab library for that or did you program the ANN by yourself? A bias is actually what a threshold is in a single perceptron, so I don't understand this parameter. If your threshold is your bias then set it initially to 1 and train it like a weight.

Comment: I programmed the ANN by myself, no matlab library used. I have taken bias weights between -1 to 1. By bias I meant the x0 node(+1).And Threshold is the minimum error I want, so I am updating weights till the error reduces to threshold

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To improve the performance and the convergence speed, add the momentum term to your weight update. This term reduces the oscillations during gradient descent and can cause gradient descent to step out of a local minima. This happens because if gradient descent reaches a plateau like structure the gradient becomes very small and the algorithm could possibly stop.

Since the momentum term adds the most recent weight update multiplied by alpha (not the same as the learning rate) to the current update, it becomes able to able to overstep such plateaus.

[image]

Source: https://page.mi.fu-berlin.de/rojas/neural/neuron.pdf

I don't know your training procedure, but you could train your network as follows:

Feed all your training data to the network. Afterwards validate the results on your test data. Do this until the result of your validation run at time t is almost equal to that of t-1, hence the error of your test data stops decreasing.